# How to Identify exact app relaunch cause while using location services in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm using location services in my iOS App, It includes  `SignificantLocationChanges` and `Geofence`.

When user travels for some distance, iOS is waking up my app. I'm identifying the app launch using '`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`' in AppDelegate as follows.

```
if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
    NSLog(@"App relaunched because of new location events.");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Normal app open");
}
```

But I'm not able to identify whether it is `SignificantLocationChanges` and `Geofence`.

Is there anything that we can identify the exact app relaunch cause using '`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`'.

I know the following delegate method for geofence:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)region {
}
```

But for some reason this method is not getting triggered.

I'm searching for the way to identify exact app relaunch cause(SLC or Geofence).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, what you're asking but I'll do my best.
Are you using something called Geofence or using the Core Location region monitoring?

If what you want to know is if your app is woken by **didEnterRegion**/**didExitRegion** or **didUpdateLocations**
I suppose you you could let the locationManager delegate methods show a local notification using something like this:

```
-(void)showBackgroundNotification:(NSString *) message {
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground && [app currentUserNotificationSettings].types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone){
        UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        note.alertBody = message;
        note.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        note.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0];
        [app scheduleLocalNotification: note];
    }
}
```

by calling that function with different string messages in each delegate function.

If I understand correctly the scenario is that the app is in a terminated state i.e. turned off. Then it gets a locationupdate and awakens. Then something happens.

Do you get didEnterRegion but not didExitregion? The problem is likely that you don't turn on your location service manually as you should.

I use this in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //for wake from terminated on location updates
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        GeoFence *fence = [GeoFence sharedInstance];
        [fence startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}
```

My Geofence class is a singleton. The two important functions other than the locationManager delegate functions are these:

```
//singleton
+ (GeoFence*) sharedInstance {
    static GeoFence *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[GeoFence alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;

        //get authorization
        if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
        [self startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

I really hope you can use this. If you need further help, let me know.
Remember to declare + (GeoFence*) sharedInstance in the header file.

Furthermore, it's important to remember that region monitoring does NOT rely on location updates. The documentation is not clear on that, but you can turn off your significantChangeLocationUpdates and still get your region boundary events. But that's another story.